# position of ComboBox

Tags: windows-phone-7

I want to some kind of option list when i hold a selection in a listbox. And i didn't find something default that does this, so i'm trying to build one of my own. So first is there such a feature in windows phone 7?

If not, then i need to open a combo box of listbox at the specified position where the selection event happened, i found out how to get the coordinates of the event as follows:

```
System.Windows.Point position = e.GetPosition(this);
double pX = position.X;
double pY = position.Y;
```

Howerver, i can't find a way to set the coordinates of the combobox for example in the view to those coordinates or so.

Help please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps what you want is a ContextMenu - there is one available in the [Silverlight Toolkit for Windows Phone](http://silverlight.codeplex.com/releases/view/75888).